# PHP y jquery validation problema al agregar validación de campos

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, validate

estoy intentando hacer un formulario en php el cual me carga datos en una base de datos que hice en mysql.
En principio solo el código del formulario y la lógina para cargarlo en la base de datos funciona bien y cumple su función.
Cuando le quise agregar con jquery validation y un archivo .js las validaciones para cada campo, ahí me dejo de funcionar. Es decir si le agrego los siguientes scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/localization/messages_es.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/registro.js"></script>
```

Funcionan las validaciones pero no me carga los datos en la base de datos. Mientras que si se los saco no tengo validaciones pero el código funciona perfectamente.
Qué puede ser? la verdad q no encuentro la razón.

Archivo registro.js e index.php:

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success:  function(label){
    label.attr('name', 'valid');
    },
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    correo: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    pass: "required",
  },
  messages: {
    correo: {
      required: "Por favor ingrese un correo electrónico."
    },
    pass: {
      required: "Por favor ingrese una contraseña."
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<?php 
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    include('includes/conexion.php');
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
  

        $cmd = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE correo = :correo');
        $cmd->execute(array(':correo' => $correo));

        $resultado = $cmd->fetch();


        if($resultado){
            if(password_verify($pass, $resultado['password'])){
                $_SESSION['idUser'] = $resultado['OID'];
                header('location:home.php');
            }else{
                $notificacion = "Error: La contraseña ingresada no es correcta.";
            }
              
        }else{
            $notificacion = "Error: El correo ingresado no esta registrado.";
        }
    }
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css"/>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>DS Travel</title>
</head>
<body>

<main class="py-4 bg-light vh-100">

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">DS TRAVEL</h1>                
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                    <form method="POST" id="myform">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="">CORREO:</label>
                            <input type="email" name="correo" id="" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="">CONTRASEÑA:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">INICIAR SESIÓN</button>

                        <a href="registro.php" class="btn btn-primary">CREAR NUEVA CUENTA</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>

</main>
    
<!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/localization/messages_es.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/registro.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Desde ya gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Bien, dejo de funcionar porque te falto el submit en el código de la validación.
te falto esta línea:

```
submitHandler: function (form) { form.submit(); }
```

Utiliza este código con la línea de código faltante.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
 debug: true,
 success:  function(label){
 label.attr('name', 'valid');
 },
 });
$( "#myform" ).validate({
 rules: {
 correo: {
 required: true,
 email: true
 },
 pass: "required",
 },
 messages: {
 correo: {
 required: "Por favor ingrese un correo electrónico."
 },
 pass: {
 required: "Por favor ingrese una contraseña."
 },
 },   
 //código faltante para el envió del formulario después de la validación
 submitHandler: function (form) {
 form.submit();
 }
});
```